# ios13 SKStoreProductViewController full screen

Tags: ios, storekit, ios13

In iOS 13, a presented `UIViewController` can be made full screen by setting `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.
But, when setting `modalPresentationStyle` on `SKStoreProductViewController`, it has no effect.

How can I make it full screen when presented?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. `SKStoreProductViewController` ignores changes to `modalPresentationStyle`, according to the Apple's developer documentation.

> This class ignores modalPresentationStyle settings, and those settings have no impact on the sheet's presentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller